# Importing external Javascript file in React gives errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to import an external Javascript file into my React app, but it throws several errors.

> Line 5:  'ActiveXObject' is not defined  no-undef
>     Line 5:  Unexpected use of 'top'         no-restricted-globals
>     Line 5:  Unexpected use of 'location'    no-restricted-globals
>     Line 5:  Unexpected use of 'location'    no-restricted-globals
>     Line 5:  Unexpected use of 'location'    no-restricted-globals
>     Line 5:  Unexpected use of 'location'    no-restricted-globals

I can't edit the Javscript file, (or properly view it, as it's minified), but it has the ActiveXObject within a try catch.

I've also tried adding the file using a script tag, and don't get the above errors, but I then can't seem to call the functions within (even using window.myFunction).

Does anyone know how I can work round these issues?

P.S. This is my first React app, so please be specific with any answers.

Thanks for any help,

Edit: Added the import below

```
import * as script from 'script.js';
```

Comment: without the code, we won't be able to help you.

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar - What code do you want? The Javascript file is minified (so I'm assuming of little use), and I'm using an import statement in the react component. (Added the import statement to the question). Thanks

Comment: also add the method that you're using.

Comment: I'm a bit confused; these are linting errors, not runtime errors. https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-undef, https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-restricted-globals

Comment: @DaveNewton - Ok, I'm not very familiar with eslint. It's stopping the project from compiling, is there a way to skip linting this imported js file?